# FaceTime audio on Mac not working (video is fine)

Tags: facetime

Whenever I try to make a FaceTime audio call from my Mac (10.9.3) I just get "Call Failed".

This happens regardless of whether I use the FaceTime Audio button in the FaceTime app or the "phone" icon/button in Messages or Contacts.

FaceTime video works fine, as does FaceTime audio from my iPhone.

Comment: does it work in any other VoiP

Comment: @Buscar웃 such as what? Skype works fine.

Comment: To what kind of device (Mac, iPhone, iPad) and OS (iOS9,8, OSX 10.10) are you trying to make a FaceTime call? Can you receive a FaceTime call from any device?

Comment: @dordio from Mac to iPhone iOS8 (haven't tried since iOS9 upgrade)